# how to replace SOLUTION_DIR

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I am trying to run a C++ demo code in Visual Studio Code on windows,
I am getting error "identifier "SOLUTION_DIR" is undefined C/C++(20)"
how I can solve this ? and how I can replace it?

```
const auto pathData = SOLUTION_DIR"data/S2.tsv";
```

here also pic shows the error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46lJE.png)

Comment: Do you use Visual Studio Code (the code editor) or the real Visual Studio (integrated programming environment)?

Comment: you need to define it when you invoke the compiler, I don't think this is a built in value

Comment: @Sebastian , its Visual Studio Code

Answer (score 1):

The C++ demo is originally meant for Visual Studio.

You can either

- define the variable with `#define SOLUTION_DIR "C:\\mypath\\todata\"` in the beginning of a header or cpp file using it,
- or you replace every occurence by the full path, e.g. `const auto pathData = "c:\\mypath\\todata\\data\\S2.tsv";` (assuming the program can accept '' and '/'
- or you provide it to the compiler command line with /D see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/d-preprocessor-definitions?view=msvc-170
- or you load the demo into Visual Studio (there is a free feature-rich Community Version available): https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/community/

Comment: I don't think `SOLUTION_DIR` is a built in define in VS either

Comment: @AlanBirtles Probably in the .vsproj / .vcxproj files delivered with the projetct, the solution path is used for a define. (Using the $(SolutionDir) macro )

Comment: thank you so much i used const auto pathData = "c:\\mypath\\todata\\data\\S2.tsv"; and its works

Comment: Glad that it worked. Would you confirm the answer on StackOverflow? Thx.